# How to prevent emacs from converting short form quote ( ' ) to literal "quote" in custom set variables, etc?

Tags: init-file

I usually use Emacs 27.1, but on a particular remote machine, it has Emacs 26.3 installed instead. After cloning my dotfiles repository onto this remote machine, all of the "custom set variables" that Emacs automatically sets for me in `init.el` have the literal word "quote" instead of the quote symbol ( ' ) that I have on my usual machine.

This is leading to git thinking that my `init.el` files have been modified when they really haven't changed. What is a good fix for this? Would shifting these custom set variables to another location help, or can I suppress this changing of quote symbol to the literal word "quote"?

Before

```
(custom-set-variables
   ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
   ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
   ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
   ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-safe-themes
     '("7451f243a18b4b37cabfec57facc01bd1fe28b00e101e488c61e1eed913d9db9" default))
   '(org-agenda-custom-commands
     '(("n" "Agenda and all TODOs"
......
```

After:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("7451f243a18b4b37cabfec57facc01bd1fe28b00e101e488c61e1eed913d9db9" default)))
 '(org-agenda-custom-commands
   (quote
    (("n" "Agenda and all TODOs"
......
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that Emacs alters your `init.el` automatically just by launching and/or exiting the program?

Comment: `'` is just a shorter way to write `quote`, so for Emacs, the file remains the same.

Comment: @lawlist My `init.el` was written in Emacs 27. When I first start the same `init.el` on a machine with Emacs 26, yes, it does change the `init.el` without telling me anything

Comment: @choroba yes, I am aware. However, `quote` is not a "function" per se in Emacs, so I wasn't really sure what to call it, thus I called it the "literal word quote". I'm sure there's better terminology, but semantically for elisp they do the mean the same thing, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop Emacs 26 from writing the custom file in this format, unless you patch Emacs 26 with the same changes which were made to Emacs 27 to make it start using the more concise syntax.

You could certainly tell your config to use a different `custom-file` when `emacs-major-version` is < 27.

Or if you didn't particularly care about changes made to that file in the Emacs 26 instance, you could make git ignore it entirely with

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged custom.el
```

(or whatever the filename is)

Git would ignore it in that working copy until such time as you manually repeat that command with `--no-assume-unchanged`

Answer (score 0):

@phils answered this.

If you really want to fiddle with this for Emacs prior to Emacs 27, you can advise the Customize functions that save settings (`custom-save-all`, `custom-save-variables`, `custom-save-faces`), by let-binding **`print-quoted`** to `t` around their bodies.

Comment: Surely you mean `custom-set-variables`, etc?

Comment: No. Why do you think so? Those are the functions that do the "printing" that's susceptible to things like `print-quoted`. Other functions use those, of course, but those are, I think, the (only) ones that need modifying to get what you want.

Comment: I'm very confused by `custom-save-variables` and `custom-save-faces`. It seems as though I don't even have `custom-save-variables` or `custom-save-faces` in my `init.el`. I only have `custom-set-variables` (the truncated example in my question) and `custom-set-faces` in my `init.el`. In fact, doing an apropos search for `custom-save` only yields `custom-save-all`

Comment: They are not used in your init file. They are used to *write* (save) customizations to your init file (or `custom-file`). See file `cus-edit.el`: `custom-save-all` calls `custom-save-variables` and `custom-save-faces` to do the work. The point is that these are the functions that actually call the print functions (which are affected by `print-quoted`).